Nginx SSL Handshake Issues with Spring Boot and Let's Encrypt Certificate
I am experiencing SSL handshake issues with my Nginx server configured to use a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate for my subdomain api.example.com, which serves a Spring Boot application. Despite following standard setup procedures, I receive the following error messages in my Nginx error logs:
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share)

Here are the details of my setup:
Environment:

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Nginx Version: 1.18.0
Spring Boot Version: 3.1.5
SSL Certificate: Let's Encrypt

Nginx Configuration:
I have configured my Nginx as follows:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example.com;
    
    # Enable TLS versions
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    # Paths to the SSL certificate and key
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;

    # Additional SSL settings
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5';

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}

SSL Certificate Check:
I verified my SSL certificate using the following command:
sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem -text -noout

The certificate is valid and not expired.
Nginx Test:
I also checked the Nginx configuration for syntax errors:
sudo nginx -t

The output shows no errors.
Firewall Settings:
I confirmed that the necessary ports are open:
sudo ufw status

The output indicates that both ports 80 and 443 are allowed.
Nginx Error Log:
Here are some relevant lines from my Nginx error log:
2024/10/03 17:14:09 [crit] 168657#168657: *30 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xx, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Additional Information:

I am using Let's Encrypt's Certbot for managing my SSL certificates.
I have restarted Nginx after making changes using sudo systemctl restart nginx.
My Spring Boot application is configured to run on port 8080 and is accessible via http://localhost:8080.

When I test it on Postman, http:// works fine, but https:// returns the error:

Error: write EPROTO 988800:error:100000f7:SSL
routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:........\src\third_party\boringssl\src\ssl\tls_record.cc:231:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

How exactly did you test this - only with postman or also with other clients? If with other clients - which client and what is the exact error you get there? Does the error happen with all clients or is it just some error you've found in the log and don't understand? Note that this error is unrelated to certificate validation or firewall settings.

@SteffenUllrich if I test it on my web application, the error relates to CORS policy. If I type the same URL in my browser (Google Chrome, latest version), the error is ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
